# Bilinear Interpolation in a Heightmap

Tags: c#, interpolation, heightmap

I've been trying to implement bilinear interpolation in a heightmap (or heightfield) class in C#, but don't really understand the math on the Wiki. Here is the implementation of the heightfield class. I have a second function, Mathf.BilinearInterpolation(...) which throws a NotImplementedException.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A flattened 2D array which contains the surface elevation data.
    /// </summary>
    public float[] Elevation { get; }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public float ElevationAtVertex(int x, int y)
    {
        return Elevation[x + y + (y * Length)];
    }

    public float ElevationAtPoint(float x, float y)
    {
        float f1 = ElevationAtVertex(Mathf.Floor(x), Mathf.Floor(y));
        float f2 = ElevationAtVertex(Mathf.Floor(x), Mathf.Ceiling(y));
        float f3 = ElevationAtVertex(Mathf.Ceiling(x), Mathf.Floor(y));
        float f4 = ElevationAtVertex(Mathf.Ceiling(x), Mathf.Ceiling(y));
        return Mathf.BilinearInterpolation(f1, f2, f3, f4);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Interpolate on the upper x floor "horizontal" line, then on x ceiling "horizontal" line and finally interpolate on "vertical" line joining the 2 previous interpolations. Note that beginning by "vertical" lines and then "horizontal" interpolation provides the same result.

```
float xratio = x-Math.floor(x) ;
float yratio = y-Math.floor(y) ;
float f12    = f1+(f2-f1)*xratio ;
float f34    = f3+(f4-f3)*xratio ;
float result =  f12+(f34-f12)*yratio ;
```